# Indefinite article in title of thesis

Tags: articles, titles

I am writing my thesis, and the title goes as follows "A study of data mining techniques for ...".
I wonder if it would be better to omit the indefinite article "a" in the title, i.e. "Study of data mining techniques for ..."
Perhaps both titles are correct, but probably one of the two is more appropriate (but I don't know which one because I am not a native English speaker).

Comment: Consider a plural. If you're planning different chapters on each technique, then _Studies in Data Mining Techniques ..._ is a possibility, and doesn't guarantee complete coverage. (I admit I'm prejudiced; my dissertation was titled [_Studies in English Generics_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/dissertation/).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **A** Study of Data Mining Techniques

suggests a description of a study somebody has undertaken, including the results.
.

> **The** Study of Data Mining Techniques

suggests a description of how we can study data mining techniques. The subject is not data mining techniques themselves, but rather it is how we can study them. Perhaps you read such a book prior to your own study.

> Study of Data Mining Techniques

could very well be taken as synonymous with **The** Study of Data Mining Techniques.

If your article is about an investigation you have performed into the subject of data mining techniques then it is better to include the indefinite article.

Answer (score 3):

For a title, "A Study of..." sounds better and [Google Books](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=ngram&rlz=1C1ARAB_enBR495BR495&oq=ngram&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2j69i65j69i60j0.1311j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22Study+of%22&tbm=bks&start=20&*) seems to yield many more results for it than for "Study of..."

> Book titles:
>
> - A Study of War
> - A Study of Humor
> - A Study of Maia Art
> - A Study of Creation